# Extracting Values from vectors

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to extract a set of points from a vector and do computation on them. The points are stored like

```
std::vector<Vector> m_points1;
m_points1.push_back(Vector( -4.0, 8.0));
m_points1.push_back(Vector( -1.0, -7.0));
m_points1.push_back(Vector( 0.0, -8.0));
m_points1.push_back(Vector( 2.0, -4.0));
m_points1.push_back(Vector( 3.0, 1.0));
```

I can't loop through it as I used to do with arrays and get the values I want. My code looks likes:

```
for(std::vector<Vector>::iterator i=points.begin();i != points.end();i++)
{
    k=i;
    for(std::vector<Vector>::iterator j=points.begin();j != points.end();j++)
    {
        if(k==j)
        {
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
                //How to get values ???
        }

    } 

}
```

How can i extract the points? and do computations on only x coordinates ?

Comment: what is p in your loop by the way?

Comment: sorry there is no p , i edited it

Comment: @NarekMinaskan - Is your goal just to get the `x` coordinates and do something with them?

Comment: i->x, j->x, k->x: Each is an iterator to a (math) Vector. You can get references Vector& with *i, *j, *k.

Comment: I am computing Lagrange barycentric weights and i need something like temp = temp * (1 / x[k]-x[j]) . As i would do with in the past and where x[k] is just the x elements. i havent worked with vectors at all

Comment: @NarekMinaskan Then all you need is `temp *= (1 / m_points1[k].x - m_points1[j].x);` Or is there something I'm mising?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Is that going to work since the m_points1 are stored like a set ? because when i am trying this the intelisence is not showing me any suggestions...

Answer (score 0):

You can use [range-based for loops](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) and avoid the iterators all together.

```
for (auto const& ptA : points)
{
    for (auto const& ptB : points)
    {
        if (&ptA == &ptB)
        {
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            // directly use ptA and ptB
        }
    }
}
```

If you are unable to use C++11, you can do the following in your `else` block

```
        else
        {
            Vector const& ptA = *i;
            Vector const& ptB = *j;
        }
```

Depending on your implementation of `Vector` you would then do something like

```
double width = ptA.x - ptB.x;
```

Comment: `If you are unable to use C++11` you can use nothing from the answer

Comment: Sorry, missed `your else block`

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. So i will write just a simple example

```
for(unsigned int i = 0 ; i<points.size() ; i++)
{
       temp = points[i](0);
}
```

to loop through a vector it needed an unsigned iterator, and to access just one of the elements u have to access it with (x) where x determines which element. in this question 0 is the x-coordinates

Answer (score 0):

```
else
{
    // do wathever you want using
    // i->x
    // i->y
    // j->x
    // j->y
    float dist = sqrt( (i->x-j->x)*(i->x-j->x)
                     + (i->y-j->y)*(i->y-j->y) );
}
```